# How to code this matrix multiplication?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I have two matrices:

```
A = [1 2; 
     3 4; 
     5 6] 

B = A'
```

The multiplication should take in the way as if row and column vector is extracted from both.
`C = B(:,i) * A(i,:)` such that for first instance (1st row and 1st column) the result would be:

```
[1 2; 
 2 4]
```

This will be summed up vertically to obtain `[3 6]`. This sum will give final answer `9`. Likewise, 2nd row & 2nd column, 3rd row & 3rd column and so on if matrix size is higher.

This final scalar value will be used for comparing which row and its corresponding column has high yield.

Comment: The question is edited. The guess of final answer is  right [9; 49; 121]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sum`:

```
result = sum(bsxfun(@times,sum(A,2), B.'),2);
```

Or in the recent version of MATLAB you can write:

```
result = sum(sum(A,2).*B.',2)
```

**Previous answer:**

You can use [permute](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html):

```
result = sum(reshape(permute(A,[2 3 1]) .* permute(A,[3 2 1]),[],size(A,1)));
```

Or in the case of `A` and `B`:

```
result = sum(reshape(permute(B,[1 3 2]) .* permute(A,[3 2 1]),[],size(A,1)));

result = [9 49 121]
```

Thanks to  @TommasoBelluzzo   and @SardarUsama .

Comment: sum(sum(permute(A,[2 3 1]) .* permute(A,[3 2 1])))(:)

Comment: Will it work if matrix size is higher than 3 dimension

Comment: Yes permute can accept arrays with multiple dimensions.

Comment: result = sum(bsxfun(@times,sum(A,2), B.',2)); This command is not working. Error:Too many input arguments (in Matlab 2017).

Answer (score 8):

Your required result is actually  mathematically equivalent of:

```
sum(A,2).^2   %or  sum(A,2) .* sum(A,2)
```

If `A` and `B` are not transpose of each other then:

```
sum(A,2).* sum(B,1).'
```

Comment: Binomial formula! Brilliant!

Comment: Very clever.. !

Comment: Your answer is Particular case, when a second matrix is transpose of first. In general A and B can be different. Anyway Thanks for Brilliant Idea.

Comment: @user9003011  it is easily adaptable for the general case as well. See the edit

Answer (score 2):

If your Matrix is of Size `Nx2`, then one possible answer is

```
A.*A * [1;1] + 2*A(:,1).*A(:,2)
```